# Photoshop - How do I fix ears that seem to stick out to the side too much in a photo?

Tags: photo, photoshop

I have a photo and I need to fix the ears. They stick out a bit and want to push them closer to the head. I tried the smudge tool on 65% and tried to gently smudge the top of the ear closer to the head but it's not very good. Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ is more appropriate. It certainly does not belong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Filters > Liquify  and then use the Forward Warp tool. You can get pretty good results by using that.

Comment: Ahh sweet thanks for the tip.